# How to use 'Using' keyword in ASP.NET page without code behind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, using-directives, using-declaration

I want to include some namespaces with their classes in my asp.net application. It is possible with `using` keyword ?

I have this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%
       SomeNamespace.Models.NewsModel getNewsDetail = ViewData["NewsDetail"] as SomeNamespace.Models.NewsModel;

       if ( getNewsDetail != null ) {
            %>
            <h2>'<%= getNewsDetail.NewsTitle%>' details</h2>
            <div class="discipline-details">
            <ul>
            <li>
            <h3> <%= getNewsDetail.NewsTitle%></h3>            
            <p><%= getNewsDetail.NewsDescription%></p>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    <%
          } else {
         %> <p class="error">No news is available. Below is listed the available news.</p>
         <div id="home-news">

        </div>
          <%
          }
     %>

</asp:Content>
```

I used MVC2 architecture ...

I want to use directly the class `NewsModel getNewsDetail = ViewData["NewsDetail"] as NewsModel`.

Thank you and sorry if my question is poor.

Comment: Too much logic in the View, you should create a custom HTML helper for that.

Comment: I totaly agree with Reigo Hein a whole class in your view ...

Comment: @Reigo: how to create own helper and where ? I have to create a new class which has a TagBuilder method ? or how ?

Comment: Yeah, you have to create a TagBuilder which takes in a HTMLHelper property and parameters that you define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) at the top of the view:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SomeNamespace" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
<%@ Import Namespace="The.Namespace" %>
```

at the top of the view but there seems to be something wrong with the original idea. You should probably use strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code block, Would you please try below: (write this code at the top of the page, page `Page` directive )

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SomeNamespace.Models" %>
```